# I can't log in with Google on the Expo app for Android/iOS (React-Native, Firebase, Expo)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

When signing in with Google on the web version of Expo, I have no issues. The difficulties arise when I try to sign in from the Expo app on Android/iOS, indicating the following error:

```
Uncaught Error
0, _auth.signInWithPopup is not a function (it is undefined)
```

Even though in my code it's defined for use with Firebase.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Platform,
} from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { GoogleAuthProvider, getAuth, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";
import {appFirebase, auth} from "../firebaseConfig";
import googleIcon from '../assets/GoogleButton.png';

export default function Ingreso() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {

    navigation.setOptions({
      headerLeft: () => null, 
      gestureEnabled: false,
    });
  }, [navigation]);

  const goLogin = () => {
    navigation.navigate("Login");
  };
  const goRegistro = () => {
    navigation.navigate("Registro");
  };
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  const handleGoogleSignIn = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const token = credential.accessToken;
        const user = result.user;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error al autenticar con Google:", error);
    });
  }  
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.padre}>
      <View style={styles.padreBoton}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cajaBotonL} onPress={goLogin}>
          <Text style={styles.textoBoton}>Iniciar Sesión</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.padreBoton}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cajaBotonR} onPress={goRegistro}>
          <Text style={styles.textoBoton}>Registrarse</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.padreBoton}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cajaBotonG} onPress={handleGoogleSignIn}>
          <Image source={googleIcon} style={{ width: 24, height: 24 }} />
          <Text style={styles.textoBotonG}>Iniciar sesión con Google</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );

}
```

I tried the option of doing it with Google Cloud's OAuth for Android and iOS, where the clientIds also did not work

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Platform
} from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { appFirebase } from "../firebaseConfig";
import googleIcon from '../assets/GoogleButton.png';
import { GoogleAuthProvider, getAuth, signInWithCredential } from "firebase/auth";
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import * as WebBrower from "expo-web-browser";

const GOOGLE_CLIENT_IDS = {
  android: '//android id',  
  ios: '//ios id',
  web: '//web id',
};

WebBrower.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export default function Ingreso() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = React.useState();
  const currentPlatform = Platform.OS;
  const clientId = GOOGLE_CLIENT_IDS[currentPlatform] || GOOGLE_CLIENT_IDS.web;

  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    clientId,
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === 'success') {
      const { id_token } = response.params;
      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
      const auth = getAuth(appFirebase);
      signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Usuario autenticado con Firebase!");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error al autenticar con Firebase:", error);
        });
    }
  }, [response]);

  

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerLeft: () => null,
      gestureEnabled: false,
    });
  }, [navigation]);

  const goLogin = () => {
    navigation.navigate("Login");
  };

  const goRegistro = () => {
    navigation.navigate("Registro");
  };
return (
    <View style={styles.padre}>
      <View style={styles.padreBoton}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cajaBotonL} onPress={goLogin}>
          <Text style={styles.textoBoton}>Iniciar Sesión</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.padreBoton}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cajaBotonR} onPress={goRegistro}>
          <Text style={styles.textoBoton}>Registrarse</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.padreBoton}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cajaBotonG} onPress={promptAsync}>
          <Image source={googleIcon} style={{ width: 24, height: 24 }} />
          <Text style={styles.textoBotonG}>Iniciar sesión con Google</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

But none of these have produced results, additionally I will leave the firebaseconfig.js. Please consider the changes with the data from the web project

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider} from "firebase/auth";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
const appFirebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(appFirebase);
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
export {auth, appFirebase, provider};
```

Comment: I doubt you can use the popup version of the sign-in function on Expo. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the web based methods on Expo Mobile (iOS and Android). You need to use

> @react-native-google-signin/google-signin

and remember that this is going to work only on development builds and not on Expo Go.

Here's the docs: [use Google authentication on expo react-native](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/google-authentication/)